# How to shade region under a function in octave?

Tags: graph, numpy, scipy, octave

I want to show the effect of threshold on FAR and FRR( basically the region under a curve with when the x-range is bounded ). To do that I need to do something like this!

[image: graph impostor vs true attempts]

If the threshold moves so does the corresponding areas bounded by the ends and the threshold.
I also want to have the two corresponding areas in different colours. Is there a way to do it in octave/python/any other tool. What is the simplest way to do so?

Also how to textbook authors draw these kind of graphs. These are not standard functions for sure.

Comment: They do not look like functions, they look more like a representation of a huge amount of data in a graph. Or, knowing how it should look, they could do a guess and draw it by hand but I doubt any reputable source will do this.

Comment: @SalvadorDali actually I would like to show every possible detail for this. I have to do a presentation on these type of analysis. So yes, a dotted line can be used to represent few things.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos Yes I also want a tool which I can use to draw by hand( mouse actions ) and the function can take the desired shape by itself. and by a mouse click or two the required area can be shaded. I want a tool which exactly does this. Doing it by writing a lot of code won't help much as this is only for illustration purpose

Comment: @noPEx, if you just want something for illustration purposes and not write a lot of code, then perhaps this is not the right place for the question. Maybe this would be better for [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

In python, you can use matplotlib's [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some fake data
x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.01)
y1 = np.exp(-(x - 6)**2 / 5.)
y2 = 2 * np.exp(-(x - 12)**2 / 8.)

plt.plot(x, y1, 'r-')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'g-')
plt.fill_between(x, 0, y1, color='r', alpha=0.6)
plt.fill_between(x, 0, y2, color='g', alpha=0.6)
```

[image: distributions]

Here, the alpha was used to create transparency and combine the two colours in the intersection area. You can also just colour that area with a different colour:

```
idx_intsec = 828
plt.fill_between(x[:idx_intsec], 0, y2[:idx_intsec], color='y')
plt.fill_between(x[idx_intsec:], 0, y1[idx_intsec:], color='y')
```

[image: distributions_yellow]

If you only want the bottom part of the graphic (ie, the function areas before and after an the threshold value), it is also easy. Let's define the threshold value in my plot as `x = 7`:

```
thres = 7.
idx_thres = np.argmin(np.abs(x - thres))
plt.plot(x[:idx_thres], y2[:idx_thres], 'g-')
plt.plot(x[idx_thres:], y1[idx_thres:], 'r-')
plt.plot([thres, thres], [0, y1[idx_thres]], 'r-')
plt.fill_between(x[:idx_thres], y2[:idx_thres], color='g', alpha=0.6)
plt.fill_between(x[idx_thres:], y1[idx_thres:], color='r', alpha=0.6)
```

[image: distributions_small]

Answer (score 5):

This is actually very easy in Octave. Using the same code for the other example (converted for Octave):

```
## create same fake data as other example
x = 0:0.1:20;
y1 = exp(-(x-6).**2 / 5);
y2 = 2 * exp(-(x-12).**2 / 8);

area (x, y1, "FaceColor", "blue");
hold on;
area (x, y2, "FaceColor", "red");
area (x, min ([y1; y2]), "FaceColor", "green");
hold off
```

I get the following figure[image: area plot]

It should be possible to change the transparency of the areas with the `FaceAlpha` but apparently that hasn't been implemented in Octave yet (one day though). In the mean time, you can pass RGB values as a workaround

```
area (x, y1,             "FaceColor", [0.0  0.0  0.8]);
hold on;
area (x, y2,             "FaceColor", [0.0  0.8  0.0]);
area (x, min ([y1; y2]), "FaceColor", [0.0  0.8  0.8]);
hold off
```